# ROS Answers SE migration: RGBD in Hydro

Tags: navigation, ccny-rgbd, pcl-conversions, ros-hydro, viso2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the following question:

http://answers.ros.org/question/91111/rgbdslam-in-ros-hydro/

I changed in my manifest.xml the line

```
  <depend package="pcl"/>
```

to

```
  <depend package="pcl_conversions"/>
```

This seems working for me. Thanks for the hint with migration of pcl with pcl_conversions.

And after the ugly thing of adding the old header file OctomapROS.h in the folder /opt/ros/hydro/include/octomap_ros/, this worked, too.

But now I get some conversion errors:

```
.../src/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/graph_mgr_io.cpp:542:67: error: request for member ‘toSec’ in ‘node->Node::pc_col.boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator-> [with T = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>]()->pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::header.pcl::PCLHeader::stamp’, which is of non-class type ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’

 .../src/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/graph_mgr_io.cpp:881:42: error: conversion from ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ to non-scalar type ‘ros::Time’ requested

 .../src/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/graph_mgr_io.cpp:882:32: error: cannot convert ‘ros::Time’ to ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ in assignment

  .../src/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/graph_mgr_io.cpp:884:32: error: cannot convert ‘ros::Time’ to ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ in assignment
```

and so on. Similiar conversion errors with ccny_rgbd and viso2_ros after changing from pcl to pcl_conversions.

So I am pretty sure something went wrong with my migration from pcl to pcl_conversions. Or is it maybe more then just editing the manifest.xml / package.xml from

```
<depend package="pcl"/> to <depend package="pcl_conversions"/>
```

?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105871/rgbd-in-hydro/) by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2013-11-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-03-26**:
@RodBelaFarin Thanks for sharing this. I am doing the similar thing with you. However, as a beginner, I do not know how to do exactly. Could you please give me a step by step instruction? (i.e. where can I find the old header file OctomapROS.h)  I appreciate it. Many thanks.

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-03-26**:
@RodBelaFarin Also, Could you please tell me which workspace you install the package? I use catkin workspace in hydro, but some guys say that only rosbuild ws is available for this package. However the rosbuild is for fuerture.http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2014-03-26**:
old octomapROS.h:
https://code.google.com/p/alufr-ros-pkg/source/browse/branches/octomap_stacks-groovy-devel/octomap_ros/include/octomap_ros/OctomapROS.h?r=3074

In the end I was NOT able to finish with RGBDSLAM. If you "just" need the 3D pointcloud, I recommend to switch to CCNY. It is much easier.

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-03-27**:
Hi @RodBelaFarin, thanks for your reply. I read the paper of CCNY, but I am not sure whether this method can generate a map of the indoor environment. There are some results of mapping on the paper, but maybe no algorithm shown. So, how can I achieve mapping use this package? Many thanks.

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-03-27**:
Hi @RodBelaFarin, I tried CCNY by your recommandation, but some errors occur, as shown in http://answers.ros.org/question/145411/error-on-installing-ccny-package-on-hydro/. Could you please tell me how to intall in on hydro?

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2014-03-27**:
http://wiki.ros.org/ccny_rgbd?distro=groovy use the quick usage guide from there. the last step "rosservice call /save_pcd_map /home/your_user_name/my_map.pcd" shows you how to save the 3D pointlcloud from your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is on the migration-site (http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL):

for every conversion error you need to make little changes in the specific lines in the code.

1.

#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>

2.

pcl_cloud.header = pcl_conversions::toPCL(pc2->header);

---

Originally posted by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) with karma: 235 on 2013-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0